# Why does jshell show this number?

Tags: java, java-17, jshell, postfix-operator

I am learning java and this logic makes me feel confused.

Isn't here `i=20(+1)+20(+1)`?

Why `41` instead of `42`?

```bash
jshell> int i = 20
i ==> 20
jshell> i=i++ + i++
i ==> 41
```

See this code run at [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/KwKdZP).

Comment: No, `++` does NOT mean `+1`.  It means "use the _current_ value of this variable, but increase it so that _next_ time you use the variable, it stores something different".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, the expression `i=i++ + i++;` is equal to `i=i++ + i;`. Why? The latter `i++` result value is never used and is not propagated. The result of the postfix addition `i++` is used as long as the value `i` is added later in the expression and the result takes the effect. However, after the latter `i++` the result value of `i` is not used.

If you want to achieve the result of `42`, you need to perform the postfix assignment (`i++`) after the whole result is assigned back to the `i` variable:

```java
int i = 20;
i = i++ + i;
i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: The correct statement should be, if you want to achieve the result of `42`, you should write down your actual intention, `i = i + 1 + i + 1;` There is no reason to use `++` here at all.

Comment: I wanted to demonstrate how the `i++` works. Of course, `i + 1 + i + 1` or even `2 * i + 2` would be better in a production code.